# mobilenetv2 tflite not expected output size with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am running into an issue with my mobilenetV2 SSD model.
I converted it using the steps detailed [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tensorflowlite.md), except the fact that I use the CLI tool `tflite_convert` for the related step.

This works fine and I am able to execute an inference, BUT the output size is not what I expected.

The following python code line

```
interpreter.get_output_details()
```

tells me that I shall retrieve 10 detection boxes :

```
[{'shape': array([ 1, 10,  4], dtype=int32), 'index': 252, 'name': 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess', 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>}, {'shape': array([ 1, 10], dtype=int32), 'index': 253, 'name': 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1', 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>}, {'shape': array([ 1, 10], dtype=int32), 'index': 254, 'name': 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2', 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>}, {'shape': array([1], dtype=int32), 'index': 255, 'name': 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3', 'quantization': (0.0, 0), 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>}]
```

So far so good, but in my `pipeline.config` file, I specified the following post_processing settings

```
post_processing {
    batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 9.99999993922529e-09
        iou_threshold: 0.6000000238418579
        max_detections_per_class: 100                                                            
        max_total_detections: 100
    }
    score_converter: SIGMOID
}
```

So I would expect the output number of detections to be 100, given that running the same model in classic tensorflow gives me 100 boxes.

Is there a way to change the output tensor size? Either at conversion or running time?

I add below the tensor output details in classic tensorflow :

```
[<tf.Tensor 'prefix/detection_boxes:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'prefix/detection_scores:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'prefix/detection_classes:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'prefix/num_detections:0' shape=<unknown> dtype=float32>]
```

where the shape is unknown, which makes sense because we can have 100 boxes or less...

Any light given of this would be really appreciated.

Please excuse me if a similar question has already being asked but I obviously did not find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rereading the `export_tflite_ssd_graph.py` script, it appears that there is an option to set the maximum number of detections that are kept.

Setting this at 100 solved my issue. I feel bad.

For those interested, I changed my export command from

```
python3 object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py \                                            
    --pipeline_config_path=$model_dir/pipeline.config \                                          
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix=$model_dir/model.ckpt \                                          
    --output_directory=$output_dir \                                                             
    --add_post_processing_op=true
```

to

```
python3 object_detection/export_tflite_ssd_graph.py \                                            
    --pipeline_config_path=$model_dir/pipeline.config \                                          
    --trained_checkpoint_prefix=$model_dir/model.ckpt \                                          
    --output_directory=$output_dir \                                                             
    --add_post_processing_op=true \                                                              
    --max_detections=100
```